# Keep console window of a new Process open after it finishes

Tags: c#

I currently have a portion of code that creates a new Process and executes it from the shell.

```
Process p = new Process();
...
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

This keeps the window open while the process is running, which is great. However, I also want to keep the window open *after* it finishes to view potential messages. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just type in your command prompt CMD /? and look at the options (hint /K)

Comment: Could you use Process.StandardOutput?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput

Comment: @Steve I looked at the /k option, but I'm not sure where to tack that on. Tried to put it into ProcessStartInfo.Arguments, but that doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: FYI, they're no longer called terminals. They're console windows.

Comment: a couple of years later, they're called terminals again.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This will open the shell, start your executable and keep the shell window open when the process ends

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
psi.Arguments = "/K yourmainprocess.exe";
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

or simply

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
psi.Arguments = "/K yourmainprocess.exe";
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
if(p != null && !p.HasExited)
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I am having "Member 'Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead" error

Comment: I faced the same error as the previous comment and even by doing it in the correct way, It doesn't keep the process window open. Just locks the UI thread until the process finished.

Comment: @Eftekhari updated, weird how this has been undetected for all these years

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 51):

It is easier to just [capture the output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx) from both the [StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [StandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx), store each output in a StringBuilder and use that result when the process is finished.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

Process p = new Process();

// redirect the output
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

// hookup the eventhandlers to capture the data that is received
p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data);

// direct start
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=false;

p.Start();
// start our event pumps
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();

// until we are done
p.WaitForExit();

// do whatever you need with the content of sb.ToString();
```

You can add extra formatting in the `sb.AppendLine` statement to distinguish between standard and error output, like so: `sb.AppendLine("ERR: {0}", args.Data);`

Comment: This is the way. Much cleaner and reliable to write this output to a log file than keeping the console window open. Great suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Be carefull espacially on switch /k, because in many examples is usually used /c.

> CMD /K Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
>
> CMD /C Run Command and then terminate

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k yourmainprocess.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding: "Member Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

This fixed the problem for me....

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
psi.Arguments = "/K yourmainprocess.exe";
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
p.WaitForExit();
```