# How to make strings for command prompt

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, command-prompt

This is my string

```
SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q "RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK='C:\app\dbName01.bak'"
```

It restores database. The command I'm using to run the command is

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

but it's doesn't work and during debugging the string is different with `\` characters added to the string.

Comment: try to add `@` just before string. like `@"your string"`.

Comment: how to you assign the string to `strCmdText`?

Comment: @ieaglle the inside `"` characters are messing with the string making it part black

Comment: @Dominik it's just a `string strCmdText = @"SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q "RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK='C:\app\dbName01.bak'""`

Comment: @George, try to use this: `@"SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q ""RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK='C:\app\dbName01.bak'""";`

Comment: The string during debugging is `"SQLCMD -E -S servName\\sqlexpress -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK='C:\\app\\dbName01.bak'\""` which is not running

Comment: @George, that's an effect of how the debugger chooses to display strings, your string (when using `@`) should be stored correctly.

Comment: Hm ok I run the command but there is no message at the command prompt. Is there a way to see if it's running and giving me an error?

Comment: @George, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23921027/183267).

Comment: Also, the Start method returns a Process object, on which you can access the StandardOutput and StandardError streams.  If you read those, it will provide whatever output is returned by the command.  Does they show an error message?

Comment: There is an error I haven't figured out `'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

Comment: @George, use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)` instead of `p.Start(psi)`. and as Ian mentioned, you can use [StardardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) and [StandardError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx). Examples are specified in links.