# Batch file xcopy issue occasionally from .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, xcopy

I have the following batch file:

```
net use %3 password /USER: username

xcopy %1 %3
echo %errorlevel% >> logfile.txt

xcopy %2 %3
echo %errorlevel% >> logfile.txt

exit
```

%1 and %2 are the source files that I want to copy into a shared directory (%3).
If I run this batch file in the traditional way (with the proper values), it works perfectly any time, but if I run this from .NET, it works only the first (maybe the second) time, and then the first xcopy returns error code 4 and the second error code is not registered (I suppose, the second xcopy doesn't run at all). Additionally, if I write `if exist %3 echo exist` I get a 9009 error code.

The .NET code:

```
 String batchFile = GetConfigValue("batch_path");

 Process process = new Process();
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.FileName = batchFile;
 startInfo.Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", file1Path, file2Path, this.sharedDirectory);
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

 process.StartInfo = startInfo;

 bool b = process.Start();
 process.WaitForExit();

 Int32 exitCode = process.ExitCode;
 process.Close();
```

The code after `process.Start()`doesn't run, and there is no exception.

Probably the process locks the network share or something like that. I tried to call `process.Dispose()` and `process.Kill()` but they didnt't help.

Comment: You might want to capture the actual output for example with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920906/keep-console-window-of-a-new-process-open-after-it-finishes/23921052#23921052) or add the redirection to your log.txt on all commands (so do `net use .... >> log.txt`)

Comment: try commenting out single operations in batch file, so you will understand where it is stuck. try adding /Y option to xcopy in order to suppress any question.

Comment: Instead of `%1` state `"%~1"` (for all argument reference instances)...

Comment: `9009` error code means _'something' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file_.  Maybe that `password`  contains `&` ampersand? Try `>>logfile.txt 2>&1 net use "%~3" "password" /USER:"username"` and use `>>logfile.txt 2>&1 xcopy "%~1" "%~3"` and distinguish `echo %errorlevel% >> logfile.txt` occurrences as `>>logfile.txt 2>&1 echo %errorlevel% "%~1"` and `>>logfile.txt 2>&1 echo %errorlevel% "%~2"`.