# how to execute batch file in c#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a batch file in C#, but although I have found multiple examples on the Internet it is not working for me.

My code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(pathBat);
psi.Verb = "runas";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Content of .bat file:

```
MIL_detection_app.exe -monitor AEE86079 2>&1 | logger.exe
pause
```

`MIL_detection_app.exe` is in the same folder. If I try to run `.bat` by double click it works fine but when I try through C# code, a console show up and disappear in less than a second.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably there is an error or it finish the job and then it is closed. Do you want to [keep console window opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921027/1997232)?

Comment: I have read all the posts related but the solutions haven't worked for me.

Comment: Are you running it from the right directory.. you supplied "runas" but no credentials.  what is in pathBat?

Comment: Hi Sinatr, the .exe that is executed by .bat file, should open a console window (and it does not). I want to see this console window. I have tried also the command waitForExit() but without success.

Comment: pathBat is the folder where .bat is. In my case: C:\Users\nraga\Desktop\C#\PruebaLanzador\PruebaLanzador\bin\x64\Debug\Current\launch.bat

Comment: dont use runas! just run it with the processtart - and maybe set the start folder.

Comment: Could you explain why I should not use runas, please? I don't understand a lot, buy I thought it was for run as administrator. If I comment this line of code, the result is the same :( Thank you

Comment: What is your c# app is it an app your user runs, or a service?  it sounds like a service or scheduled task.. runas usually is for running as different credentials which you then supply..  it just sounds like those exes are not pathed.

Comment: Voting to close are there are numerous discussions on SO around this,

Comment: My app is a launcher for another app. It is supposed to connect to a shared resource, download the last version and run it. Until now, this process was manual by double click the file launch.bat, but now, I need my app (which is a launcher) does it and executes launch.bat. I hope to have make clear myself, thanks.

Comment: Setting the start folder worked for me! Thank you very much! @BugFinder