# How to run npm command inside a class library in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, npm, class-library

I am making a **class library** project , its goal , for the moment , is to run a JavaScript project through an npm command thanks to a c# method call .

**The npm command** :

> npm start

The JavaScript project (made with reactJS ) resides within the class library project .

**The Class library ( to call ) :**

```
namespace DoGutenberg
{


  public class Run   
{  


public void start ()  
{

            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "/C npm start ";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);


  }
}
}
```

**The method call from another asp.net project :**

```
using DoGutenberg;

  var a = new DoGutenberg.Run();

            a.start();
```

**The sripts field within package.json inside the JavaScript project  :**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

The problem is that when i call **start()** method from another asp.net project , after importing the class library as a reference for sure , npm errors are generated in npm command window that i couldn't catch since the window is keeping hiding fast .

**Any help with that please ? or what can be any other outlet to run this JavaScript project ?**

Comment: Try adding a /K to the command line to keep it open.  Your issue is probably that you need to specify the directory containing the commands as the `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`, but you definitely need to be able to read those messages to troubleshoot properly

Comment: @Grax adding /K to the command line didn't fix the command window , it stills hiding fast  .

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920906/keep-console-window-of-a-new-process-open-after-it-finishes

Answer (score 0):

By adding a Console.ReadKey() in the dll your CMD window should persist:

```
public void start()  
{
string strCmdText;
strCmdText = "/C npm start ";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
Console.ReadKey();
}
```